# As.formula does not work in loop? (adjusting regression)

Tags: r, statistics, regression

So I'm writing a loop to recursively remove the least significant coefficients from a large regression.

Everything looks good until the as.formula() line, which gives the error code that a specific regressor does not exist. I checked the dataframe and it's there and everything looks alright. the paste() is fine. I don't understand what's wrong.

```
reg <- lm(price ~ .^2, data.cards)
coeff <- as.data.frame(summary(reg)$coefficients[,4, drop = FALSE])
while(coeff[which.max(coeff[,1]),]>0.01){
  least.significant <- rownames(coeff[which.max(coeff[,1]), , drop = FALSE])
  reg.equation <-as.formula(paste(least.significant, collapse = "-" ))
  reg <- update(reg, reg.equation)
  coeff <- data.frame(summary(reg)$coefficients[,4, , drop = FALSE])
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please provide data with your questions. It is sometimes difficult to guess what is going on without a reproducible example, but I think the following demonstrates the issue.

```
reg <- lm(mpg ~ .^2, mtcars[, 1:4])
coeff <- as.data.frame(summary(reg)$coefficients[,4, drop = FALSE])
while(coeff[which.max(coeff[,1]),]>0.01){
  least.significant <- rownames(coeff[which.max(coeff[,1]), , drop = FALSE])
  reg.equation <-as.formula(paste(least.significant, collapse = "-" ))
  reg <- update(reg, reg.equation)
  coeff <- data.frame(summary(reg)$coefficients[,4, , drop = FALSE])
}
```

> Error in class(ff) <- "formula" : attempt to set an attribute on NULL

Note that `least.significant` in the first step is `"disp:hp"`, and this cannot be coerced into a formula:

```
as.formula("disp:hp")
as.formula("disp:hp + hp")
```

etc, but `as.formula("~ disp:hp")` would work. There is a useful function for this, `reformulate`, which takes a character vector of terms and response, so in the example below, you just need to change the `reg.equation <-` line to work:

```
reg <- lm(mpg ~ .^2, mtcars[, 1:4])
coeff <- as.data.frame(summary(reg)$coefficients[,4, drop = FALSE])
while(coeff[which.max(coeff[,1]),]>0.01){
  least.significant <- rownames(coeff[which.max(coeff[,1]), , drop = FALSE])
  reg.equation <- reformulate(setdiff(names(coef(reg)[-1]), least.significant), '.')
  reg <- update(reg, reg.equation)
  coeff <- data.frame(summary(reg)$coefficients[, 4, drop = FALSE])
}
coef(reg)
# (Intercept)         cyl        disp    cyl:disp 
# 49.03721186 -3.40524372 -0.14552575  0.01585388
```